# Switch Fragments while Maintaining State

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Decided to rewrite this question:

I have three fragments call them A B C.  Each has a view with some fields for the user to fill out.  The user should be able to use a menu to switch between the different fragments.  If the user fill outs information in fragment A and then switch to C fills out more information and then switches back to A the information the user typed in A should still be there.

I think I need to be using the FragmentManager somehow but I can't figure out the right combination of adds/ replaces / attaches ... that are required to make it work the way I want.

Can someone please provide a code snippet that would allow me to switch between fragments while maintaining each fragments view state.

Current Working Solution:

mContent is the active fragment and is a private member variable of the activity.

If anyone sees something wrong with this approach or a way to make it more efficient / more robust please let me know!

```
public void switchContent(String fragmentTag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if ( fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( fragmentTag ) != mContent ) {
        if ( !mContent.isDetached() ) {
            transaction.detach( mContent );
        }

        if ( fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( fragmentTag ) == null ) {
            if ( fragmentTag.equals( "details" ) ) {
                mContent = ScheduleDetailsFragment.newInstance();
            } else if ( fragmentTag.equals( "notes" ) ) {
                mContent = ScheduleNotesFragment.newInstance();
            } else if ( fragmentTag.equals( "exceptions" ) ) {
                // @TODO - Create Exceptions Fragment
            }
        } else {
            mContent = ( SherlockFragment ) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( fragmentTag );
        }
        if ( mContent.isDetached() ) {
            transaction.attach( mContent );
        } else if ( !mContent.isAdded() ) {
            transaction.add( R.id.content_frame, mContent, fragmentTag );
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

Thank You,
Nathan

Comment: Is your state being lost with this method, using .detach()? Is your view being lost when you reattach? Or this gives the correct results?

Comment: This gives the correct results, just not sure if it adheres to fragment best practices / if it can be made better.

Answer (score 1):

> I based my code of one of the examples provided but it returns a new fragment everytime a menu item is clicked so state information is lost.

If your pages hold onto some form of state/session, returning a new `Fragment` for every navigation event is a very poor user experience, and also not so good on memory usage.

I'd recommend having your sliding menu use the `FragmentManager` in your main `Activity` to maintain all of your `Fragments` that you switch between. It will manage all of their states, and you can retrieve them using `findFragmentByTag(String tag)`. You would just need to ensure that each `Fragment` saves any state (values/data that changes after initial creation) that you add in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and restores it in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. I'm not sure how the sliding menu you are using manages that currently, so this may not be possible. Hope this helps at least get you going in the right direction.

**Edit: Updated answer for updated question -**
Here is how I would switch the `Fragments`. By using replace, you will completely switch the `Fragments`, while reusing the already created ones. In order for your Fragments to saved/restore their state, you need to refer to my answer above. If that is unclear, search for some examples of how to save state in `Fragments` and `Activities`.

```
public void switchContent(String fragmentTag) {

    // If our current fragment is null, or the new fragment is different, we need to change our current fragment
    if (mContent == null || !mContent.getTag().equals(fragmentTag)) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Try to find the fragment we are switching to
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

        // If the new fragment can't be found in the manager, create a new one
        if (fragment == null) {
            if (fragmentTag.equals("details")) {
                mContent = ScheduleDetailsFragment.newInstance();
            }
            else if (fragmentTag.equals("notes")) {
                mContent = ScheduleNotesFragment.newInstance();
            }
            else if (fragmentTag.equals("exceptions")) {
                // @TODO - Create Exceptions Fragment
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, we found our fragment in the manager, so we will reuse it
        else {
            mContent = (SherlockFragment) fragment;
        }

        // Replace our current fragment with the one we are changing to
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent, fragmentTag);
        transaction.commit();

        getSlidingMenu().showContent();
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing since we are already on the fragment being changed to
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed my code so that the main activity has an array of the different fragments.  But even though I am using the same fragments over it appears they are still losing all state data.  If I use oneSaveInstanceState then won't I have to manually set all the ui elements back to what they were before. Is there no better way of doing that?

Comment: If you don't use the `FragmentManager` to manage your `Fragments` (hint hint), you have to manually save and restore your array of `Fragments` in your `Activity`. It's doable, but wasteful since the `FragmentManager` does it for you. 

The simply process for `onCreate` and `onSaveInstanceState` is save all state you use in `onSaveInstanceState`, and setup/restore those variables in `onCreate`. Most views restore their state for you. Basically you don't need to do much more than setup your views in `onCreate` and restore any custom state you may have added.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just want to `detach` the fragments from the UI here not remove them from the `FragmentManager` as well like `replace` does.